Custom view on admin main page
I want to show some information on the admin index.html, but I do not want to use context processors for this, but have my own view.
So I tried like described in the docs and discussed here.
My app is called virtual, so I did:
in virtual/admin.py:
class VirtualAdminSite(admin.AdminSite):
    index_template = "virtual/admin_index.html"

    def index(self, request, extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}
        return super().index(request, extra_context)

admin_site = VirtualAdminSite(name="virtualAdminSite")

in virtual/apps.py:
class VirtualAdminConfig(AdminConfig):
    default_site = "virtual.admin.VirtualAdminSite"

in project/settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS  = ["virtual.apps.VirtualConfig",
                   "virtual.apps.VirtualAdminConfig", ...]

I then run in to the error:
ImportError: Module "virtual.admin" does not define a "VirtualAdminSite" attribute/class

If I use "django.contrib.admin" instead of virtual.apps.VirtualAdminConfig everything works just fine.
so two questions:

why does this error happen, I feel I copied that straight from the docs?
I assumed I could add some variables in the VirtualAdminSite extra_context and show them in the index template by using {{ variable_name }} - is this correct?


While I can't reproduce, and so can't figure out why you're seeing, that error, I think you're ultimately going to want to set the app_index_template field and override the app_index(...) method on your VirtualAdminSite.
